Getting bash function result from python
I was wondering if there is some way to execute a bash func call from python.
I've tried to run something like this
import subprocess 

print(subprocess.run("_get_app_creation_timestamp", shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8").strip())

Shell function definition could be something like this
BASH_FUNC__get_app_creation_timestamp%%=() {  _get_app | jq '.metadata.creationTimestamp' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'

But I just get an empty string.
From a shell script code, call would be something so easy like
TIME="$(_get_app_creation_timestamp)"

My main goal is porting shell script into python but it's not being so easy as I thought :)

Apparently subshell created via subprocess don't have this function, try to source it first:
subprocess.run("source path_to_file_with_function && _get_app_creation_timestamp"...

Or better yet, change it into a standalone script so you don't need to separately enable interactive features when your use case is clearly a noninteractive one.

Using text=True gets rid of some of the pesky decoding etc. You can add encoding='utf-8' if Python's default encoding is something else than what your shell is configured for; but on modern platforms you would generally expect UTF-8 everywhere (except in some holdouts like Java and the Windows ghetto).

Are you sure that subprocess.run is actually using bash? Try run('_get_app_creation_timestamp', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash').

Since your objective is porting to Python, it seems like trying to run shell functions via a subprocess would be counterproductive.  I suppose that mirrors something in the original shell script, but few shell idioms are very Pythonic.  Surely part of porting shell scripts to Python would be porting the shell functions they use?

Thanks you all for your help. I've tried setting shell=True but it didn't work. I'm thinking about a workaround, a kind of Frankenstein which keeps shell info running functions and saving in env variables and later accessing to those variables via Python.

@JohnBollinger you are absolutely right. But this was to be an easy change to add functionality and doing that could mean me refactoring thousands of lines of code. I will create a Jira task for that. But I need a fast approach for the moment.

The shell function you are trying to use is just parsing some json.  Surely it would take less time to do that in python than the time you've already spent trying to invoke it in a shell!   You might just want to invest some time figuring out how your original environment is defining the functions (eg, are definitions sourced from some system level file that is sourced in an interactive startup file) and define them similarly.  (eg, write your own shell wrappers intended for non-interactive use that source the same definitions.).  But it's almost certainly better to port to Python.
